# how to disable missing '@override' annotation check in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I want change codes, in run time Compile classes. but I can't change codes of this classes.

I search and realized that i have the option to deactivate.
This option's path in eclipse is : ***windows - preferences - java - compiler - errors/warning*** . 
but I can't find this path and option in last version on Android Studio (1.2.1.1).

please show me this option (**missing '@override' annotation**), in last version of Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is in `Settings -> Editor -> Inspections`. By default it should be disabled

[image]